# Jar print convert and print "$?" to 0

Tags: command-line, bash, java, eclipse

I have a clipscode which I want to insert in my database I wrote a Java prog for that and it is running fine in eclipse IDE if my clips code contains "$?" it preserved as it is in eclipse IDE. see the output of eclipse IDE

```
(defrule through_the_use_of_1364;through the use of

(Head-Level-Mother-Daughters ?h1 ?l1 ?m1 $? ?m $?)

=>

(printout debug_rule "(through_the_use_of_1364)" crlf))
```

The problem occurs When I made a jar of the program and run on my terminal  "$?" is converted as 0.
see the output of terminal is given below.

```
(defrule through_the_use_of_1364;through the use of

(Head-Level-Mother-Daughters ?h1 ?l1 ?m1 0 ?m 0)

=>

(printout debug_rule "(through_the_use_of_1364)" crlf))
```

Please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell is interpreting `$?` as the exit status of the previous command.

To prevent shell interpretation:

Use quotes around `$?`:

```
(Head-Level-Mother-Daughters ?h1 ?l1 ?m1 "$?" ?m "$?")
```

Or

```
(Head-Level-Mother-Daughters ?h1 ?l1 ?m1 '$?' ?m '$?')
```

Or escape `$` with `\`:

```
(Head-Level-Mother-Daughters ?h1 ?l1 ?m1 \$? ?m \$?)
```

Comment: The last option worked for me.                                                                                                                                                                                                                      (Head-Level-Mother-Daughters ?h1 ?l1 ?m1 \$? ?m \$?)